# NetSuite Overwrite Value in Transaction Body Field with Default Value

Tags: sql, netsuite

Background: I created a custom due date field on Sales Orders.

I have a SQL formula to calculate the due date based on the Terms and the Start Date field in NetSuite. (Please see below) Is it possible to overwrite the due date field manually, even when Terms have been specified?

[Transaction body field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW4TK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you ✔️ "Store Value" on your custom field record.